# Post SOAP Request to MS Dynamics NAV WS

Tags: xml, soap, postman, microsoft-dynamics, navision

In Postman I connect to MS Dynamics NAV Web Services via NTLM Authentication, Status 200 OK.

But posting XML SOAP request does not insert XML values into NAV table.

Need help troubleshooting issue or scrypt that retrieves NAV's error response

**CODE**:

```
POST /DynamicsNAV/XX/XXXXXX/XXXXXX/XXXXXWebService HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxecommerce.xxxx.com:####
Authorization: Basic RGlhbUZvdW5kcnk6SmV3ZWwhMjAxOQ==,NTLM TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAF4AAAAYABgAdgAAAAAAAABIAAAAFgAWAEgAAAAAAAAAXgAAAAAAAACOAAAABYKIogUBKAoAAAAPZABpAGEAbQBmAG8AdQBuAGQAcgB5ACpXuYEsniS5AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOfUxlJIGBMW0Bzq8JrpIXWoUPZ9DJTNwQ==
Content-Type: text/xml
SOAPAction: 
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 26ddaa1b-84a5-44ad-9f5c-5a8459671747,112cab04-f290-461b-afd3-37ba650cdb57
Host: xxxxx.xxxxx.com:7047
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 2511
Connection: keep-alive

cache-control: no-cache
```

**XML**:

```xml
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
    <CreateOrders xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/CustomerDocumentWebService">
    <orderXML>
    <DocumentHeader xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/XXXXXXX/CreateOrder">
      <Purchase_Order_No>PO55443322</Purchase_Order_No>
      <Ship_to_No>1002</Ship_to_No>
      <Ship_for_No></Ship_for_No>
       <Ship_to_Contact></Ship_to_Contact>
       <Ship_to_Name></Ship_to_Name>
       <Ship_to_Name2></Ship_to_Name2>
        <Ship_to_Address></Ship_to_Address>
        <Ship_to_Address2></Ship_to_Address2>
        <Ship_to_City></Ship_to_City>
        <Ship_to_PostalCode></Ship_to_PostalCode>
        <Ship_to_Country></Ship_to_Country>
        <Contact_Phone_No>999-999-9999</Contact_Phone_No>
        <Consumer_Order_No>CO1234567</Consumer_Order_No>
         <Order_Date>06/27/2019</Order_Date>
         <Requested_Delivery_Date>06/30/2019</Requested_Delivery_Date>
        <Shipping_Carrier_Service>UPS</Shipping_Carrier_Service>
        <Shipping_Service_Level>UPS2</Shipping_Service_Level>
        <Partial_Shipment_Selection></Partial_Shipment_Selection>
        <DocumentLine>
        <Document_Line_No>1</Document_Line_No>
        <SKU></SKU>
        <Item_No>31-DF100CEP-E.00</Item_No>
        <Size>06.50</Size>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
         <Unit_Price></Unit_Price>
         <Requested_Delivery_Date></Requested_Delivery_Date>
        <DocumentCommentLine>
        <Comment_Line_Code>ITEMPER</Comment_Line_Code>
        <Comment_Line_Description>Love Always</Comment_Line_Description>
        </DocumentCommentLine>
        </DocumentLine>
       <DocumentCommentHeader>
      <Comment_Header_Code>GIFTMESS</Comment_Header_Code>
        <Comment_Header_Description>U R the One!</Comment_Header_Description>
        </DocumentCommentHeader>
       </DocumentHeader>
      </orderXML>
     </CreateOrders>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please post the code from your codeunit that is published as the web service as well.

Comment: I think that the problem is that you need to fill more data in that purchase order. Please post the codeunit with your code for more help.

Answer (score 1):

sorry to take so long responding.
We determined that the issue was with Header Key SOAPAction value
Needed to enter Code Unit's URN value
Consider this closed

Comment: I was trying to call Read method from POSTMAN on dynamics NAV 2018 WS but surprisingly it was returning me the wsdl definition on every call. Fortunately adding the SOAPAction=Read helped me to resolve the error. Thanks for the post!